# TCP is acting weird

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm programming my own TCP client, and it is acting a bit weird.

The way the client works is by checking if the last byte of the received bytes is a \0 character. If it is, it converts the previous data in the buffer into text, and triggers an event with that text as the event's argument.

However, something odd happens if I attempt to send 2 strings at the same time. In that case, they actually get received as one string, which is weird if you ask me.

How can I fix this?

I didn't include code samples since it would be quite large to include. If you insist, add a comment and request it, and I'll post it.

Comment: Best would be if you could reproduce the problem in twenty or thirty lines... Maybe just include the snippets showing how you send and receive on the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a stream so what you are describing is totally normal when you send multiple packets from one side of the connection, the other side may receive everrything at the same time.

Well the windows kernel is in fact fighting AGAINST you in this, as it try as much possible to concatenate packets. If you want to disable this (It's called the Nagle Algorithm) from the side that is sending the data :

```
TcpClient client = // something
client.NoDelay = true;
```

But TCP will always represent a stream, so you should be prepared for it.

In your case it mean that you should parse the returned string, find all `'\0'` and send an event for each of them.

Answer (score 5):

If you're transmitting two strings over the same socket from two different threads, then yes, they will get interleaved. For this, you need some sort of thread sync (in .NET, a `lock()` statement should do it), or use two different sockets.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong but I suspect you actually sent the string without the null (\0 character).

When your client received the data, it automatically appends the null character to construct a string.

So, when you send 2 strings at the same time, they get merged together without the null character. On the receiving end, it is reconstructed as a single string with only a single null.

Try to send the data with len + 1, or pad the string with a null character before sending.

Comment: i would add that TCP is a stream protocol: successive calls to `send()` do not imply multiple return values from `recv()`, as data may be appended into a single tcp frame. data are considered a single continuous stream of bytes, and you are responsible for separating the different part of your stream by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> However, something odd happens if I attempt to send 2 strings at the same time.

alöready has the solution. Do not send them at the same time. Queue the second string,s end it after the first. This is btw. totally not a network problem - the socket API just is not atomic and thread safe per definition.